# what tools are available to apply correct page numbers to a composite tex output pdf file?

Tags: page-numbering, viewers, multiple-files

this question is relevant to the full-issue pdf files of tugboat, as made
available for electronic reference or download.  all articles are always
posted individually, but a single front-to-back pdf file is much more
convenient for downloading.

a single issue of tugboat will always contain items prepared with plain
tex, pdflatex and usually xetex, and there may also be items prepared
with context or otherwise requiring lua(la)tex.  thus it is impossible
to prepare a full issue as an unbroken unit.  also, the table of contents
is always on the back cover.

a recent (sensible) suggestion was to package the electronic issue
with the toc at the front, followed by the rest of the contents in the
same order as the print edition.

the tool now used to package the full-issue pdf is ghostscript [9.21].
this merely concatenates the separate article files.  it does not
create bookmarks or any links; to add these would place an unreasonable
burden on an already overworked volunteer.

after issue 38:2 was packaged in this manner, i noticed while checking
the pdf that the page numbers indicated in the box between the navigation
arrows and the "page mm of nnn" message did not correspond to the numbers
on the actual pages.  since one purpose of a toc is to show starting
page numbers, the ability to type in a page number to access a
particular item directly is highly desirable.

i use acrobat to read pdf files; karl berry, who prepares the output
files, does not, and when i mentioned this disconnect, he didn't know
what i was referring to -- his pdf reader, xpdf [v.3], displays the
page information in a somewhat different way.

finally, the question: what (freeware) tools are available for which
at least a starting page number can be specified so that the logical
page number of a page in the pdf file will be the same as the page
number shown on the page image as viewed on the screen?

**addendum:**
in response to a (now deleted) comment asking why we don't ask for source files
for tugboat submissions, *we do*!  the whole excruciating process of putting
together a tugboat issue has been detailed in the "production notes"
column that appears in the
[TUG@BachoTeX 2017 proceedings](http://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents38-2.html)
issue.  (this link goes to the issue toc; the referenced article appears on
page 263.)

**addendum #2:**
in answer to a request for details on how the page numbers appear in the two
mentioned browsers, here they are: 
 - xpdf: Page 1  of 183 
 - acrobat: 284 (1 of 183) 
the arrangement of pages in the file is as follows: 
   cover 4 (toc), cover 2, 109 (title page) - 288. cover 3

Comment: Exactly ho are the pdf merged? Does the online version contain hyperlinks? Are there any data others (members perhaps) can play with? And at least learn new tricks. I usually use pdfpages but that might not be flexible enough.

Comment: A few of the articles are already accessible without TUG membership, including [the referenced article](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-2/tb119prod.pdf) on TUGboat “Production notes”. It mentions “To do the concatenation, we’ve used a variety of tools, most commonly Ghostscript and `pdfjam` (`ctan.org/pkg/pdfjam`) of late. ConTEXt and `pdftk` have also been useful. Different tools are needed as years go by and software and systems change (for no convincing reason).” I think it would be worth mentioning exactly what was the discrepancy seen between the page numbers, in acrobat and in xpdf.

Comment: we have some success at converting to postscript, adjusting links, (eg changing cross document links to internal links within the concatenated files) just using sed, then making some other sed script replacements and then distilling the whole lot back to pdf.

Comment: I don't quite understand. The numbers of the content pages are running from 109-288, yet you want the numbers Karl sees, which run from 1-183 rather than (the admittedly even more confusing) 284 (1 to 183) - what? Is the last page 288+183 (183 of 183)?

Comment: The electronic table of contents or whatever you call it is even more confusing than the page numbering.

Comment: @cfr -- the contents page (the first page in the concatenated pdf file) is cover 4 of the print version; it has not been redone for the electronic file.  the second page is cover 2 of the print version.  the third page is the title page of the issue which has the assigned number 109, but this number is not printed.  ordinary numbered pages (from the print version) run from 110-288, and cover 3 is the last page in the concatenated file.  the total number of pages is 183.  (issue 1 had 108 pages, and the printed page numbers run continuously through the year.)  is this clearer now?

Comment: So it is starting at 284 for unknown reasons? I seems it should start at 288. Or are the covers somehow separate, so it has 284-4? (But then why does the cover count at all?) Anyway, apparently other people understand it, so probably it is just me.

Comment: @cfr This is what I understand. The previous issue (TUGboat 38:1) ended on page 108. The desired goal is that the 183 pages in the PDF of this issue must be numbered (labelled) as `c4`, `c2`, `109`, `110`, … `288`, `c3`. (Or something like that; I'm not sure of labelling of the cover pages.) (Double-check to count it, these labels are 183 in total.) (So when acrobat says `284 (1 of 183)`, the 284 is some undesired and meaningless label that should never have occurred, because 284 is the number of [an actual page](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-2/tb119chest.pdf) printed with that number.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Usually, viewers don't show meaningless labels. You can figure out the relationship. Here, it seems really unobvious what that is. Not that it probably matters solution-wise. I was just curious.

Comment: @cfr Hmm interesting perspective. I was thinking more of the problem of what was required; I didn't think of the problem of how the PDF may have ended up in its current state with such strange numbers being shown. I guess there are many ways that something can go wrong… I agree it seems really unobvious here as you said. Assuming the invocation didn't input very incorrect numbers, I can probably think of explanations for how acrobat could have ended up showing the first page as any of 1, 4, 106–109, 181–183, 289–291, but not 284. :-) Just a failure of imagination on my part I'm sure!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Page labels are added as array in the `/Catalog` of the PDF file. Since the PDF file is generated by ghostscript, it can be set by the `pdfmark` operator in a PostScript file and added to the input files for ghostscript, for example:

```bash
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=combined.pdf pagelabels.ps file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf
```

File `pagelabels.ps`:

```ps
[
  {Catalog} <<
    /PageLabels <<
      /Nums [
        0 << /P (cover ) /S /D >>
        2 << /S /D /St 109 >>
        182 << /P (cover 3) >>
      ]
    >>
  >>
/PUT pdfmark
```

The following syntax elements of PDF are needed:

- Numbers (`0`, `2`, `109`, `182`)
- Names are preceded by a slash (`/PageLabels`, `/P`, `/S`, `/D`, `/St`)
- Strings can be given in parentheses (`(cover )`, `(cover 3)`).
- Arrays use square brackets as delimiters (`[` ... `]`).
  The array elements can be of any object type.
- Dictionaries use double angle brackets (`<<` ... `>>`).
  They contain key-value pairs. The keys are always names, values can be any object. For example, the fourth object in the `/Nums` array is a dictionary `<< /S /D /St 109 >>`) with two keys `/S` and `/St`. Values are `/D` for key `/S` and `109` for key `/St`.
- Comment character is `%` as in TeX.

The elements in the `/Nums` array in the dictionary `/PageLabels` declare the page labels.
A zero-based index is followed by a dictionary defining the page labels for the pages starting with this page. The keys in the dictionary:

- `/P` specifies a *prefix*.
- `/S` sets the *style* for the page number. The styles with their LaTeX equivalents:

  - `/D` ≙ `\arabic`
  - `/R` ≙ `\Roman`
  - `/r` ≙ `\roman`
  - `/A` ≙ `\Alph`
  - `/a` ≙ `\alph`
- `/St` sets the *start* page, default is 1.

The specification from above generates the following page labels:

- `0 << /P (cover ) /S /D >>`:

  - Page 1: `cover 1`
  - Page 2: `cover 2`
- `2 << /S /D /St 109 >>`:

  - Page 3: `109`
  - Page 4: `110`
  - ...
  - Page 182: `288`
- `182 << /P (cover 3) >>` or `182 << /P (cover ) /St 3 >>`:

  - Page 183: `cover 3`

Further reading:

- [PDF reference](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), [PDF 1.7 (first edition)](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf), section "12.4.2 Page Labels"
- [pdfmark Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdfmark_reference.pdf)

However, page labels are not supported by all PDF viewers.

- Viewers with support for page labels:

  - Adobe Reader
  - [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince)
  - [SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html)
  - [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/)
  - Mozilla Firefox (builtin viewer)

**Hint:** Some viewers (Okular, for example) do not reserve much space for the labels. The labels should be pretty short to prevent the need for horizontal scrolling to see all of the label.

- Viewers without support, that only show the absolute page number:

  - [xpdf](http://www.xpdfreader.com/) v3.04
  - Google Chrome (builtin viewer) v61

Comment: If you know, could you add Okular to the appropriate list since it is the equivalent of Evince on KDE-based systems?

Comment: @cfr I have tried the Cygwin port of Okular, version 17.04. The loading time of about 70 seconds is much too slow for practical usage. Also the place for the page labels is pretty small, only about four chars can be seen without the need for scrolling, even if there is more than enough place left and right of the page number display.

Comment: Okular is my default PDF viewer .... But I am running it on a different OS, I guess.